# reCaptcha reputation error Magento 234 newsletter subscription

Tags: google-recaptcha, magento234

Footer newsletter subscription display error **You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low.**

I have used google invisible captcha.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error was related to the CSP which came in Magento 2.3 and Magento 2 document suggests to create a custom module to whitelist the third-party scripts such as Google API, Google Recaptcha.